# IIS deployment issue

Tags: iis

I am running IIS in a standalone Windows Server 2012, and getting a mysterious issue:
I have a webapi (developed with .NET 4.6) which impelement SCEP protocol under the HTTP GET, and the app folder is in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\app\mywebapi.

If I create a virtual directory under Default Web Site,then it works (for instance, http://localhost/app/mywebapi). 
Test procedures:

1. using browsers to surf: http://localhost/app/mywebapi?operation=GetCACert
2. using sscep (an command line test tool) sscep getca -u http://localhost/app/mywebapi -c ca.crt

Results: Both cases work

if I create a new website, then it does not work in some case (for instance: http://mywebapi) (hosts file has been edited, so it understand mywebapi as a hostname already)

1. using browsers to surf: http://mywebapi?operation=GetCACert
2. using sscep (an command line test tool) sscep getca -u
   http://mywebapi -c ca.crt

Results:

1. OK
2. does not work, IIS returns 404

Does anybody know about this issue?

Comment: What do you get when you just try to ping from CMD that new hostname? If you don't find it then try maybe to reset by using `ipconfig /flushdns` and then try again to ping..

Comment: Take a look at your IIS logs `c:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\*`, It might give a hint about whether it is reaching your IIS (at all), and what was requested.

Comment: Thanks, no problem with dns, and i configured hosts file and tests are all done in the same machine. @tgolish: Yes, checked, the requests reached IIS, but no more useful info: See below 2019-03-13 01:55:39 127.0.0.1 GET /service/scep operation=GetCACert&message=CAIdentifier 80 - 127.0.0.1 - - 404 0 2 577
2019-03-13 01:55:42 127.0.0.1 GET /service/scep operation=GetCACert&message=CAIdentifier 80 - 127.0.0.1 - - 404 0 2 4